# Objective-C pulling USB iDevice model & iOS Version data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos

I've been trying to understand the USB interfacing of Obj-C but am getting reamed

What's a good way to access the IODevice's version number and model number?

I've found information on pulling the device's UIID, but I can't seem to mess around with the other data